# Directus: Hide items to other users

Tags: directus

Scenario:

- I have 3 users with different roles (**admin**, **siteAadmin**, and **siteBadmin**).
- I have a collection which is consumed by 2 sites (**siteA**, **siteB**).
- a custom **hook** is setup for the collection to send external email to admin user
- Posting data via **public** API.

Goal:
I want to hide the data coming from siteA on siteBadmin listing. Is that possible without creating a custom page? Or is it best to create a duplicate collection for siteB instead?

Any other alternative to achieve the goal?

TIA

Comment: If you're trying to hide public data, that is a bit harder/weird... you'd need to do that with filters, but there'd be nothing stopping someone from seeing the other day since that bypasses permissions.

Comment: @RANGER I'm trying to reuse the existing collection used by siteA for siteB but I don't want them to share the data recorded which is coming from their own separate sites.

Comment: You can duplicate the collection, or build a custom interface that limits the relational items you can select based on some filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can currently use the "role" permissions to restrict a collection's items to a certain role. This is based on an "owner" field... so you would need to ensure the collection has that field and permissions are setup accordingly:

https://docs.directus.io/guides/permissions.html#read

In the near future (2-3 months) we'll be releasing a new version of Directus with dynamic permissions that will let you do this in more flexible ways:

https://github.com/directus/api/issues/511